# Draw diagonal line based on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Xcode 5, I am trying to make an app that allows the user to draw a line based on touch. I would have this working using `UIBezierpath` but then I am not able to remove the last line once the user tries to draw a new one. What method would I use to draw a line between `touchDown` and `touchUp` that can be easily deleted? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIBezierPath Removal Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507359/uibezierpath-removal-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the UIBezierPath to construct a path which you then assign to a CAShapeLayer. You then add that layer as a sublayer to some view you already have in the interface. To delete the line, remove the layer.